# How to ask user for input

Tags: c#

I was wondering how to ask the user for input and then check for certain attributes of the input and display the output separated by commas except for the last output. Here's what I have so far. I'm struggling with asking the user for input, and also getting rid of the comma at the end of the output:

```
using System;
class TestClass
{
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {

 int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 if (x < 0 || x > 25)
   Console.WriteLine("sorry, that number is invalid");

 else
   while (x <= 30)
   {  
     if(x <= 30)
       Console.Write(string.Join(",", x));
       Console.Write(", ");

       x = x + 1;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the input? Provide an example of the input and output you are expecting.

Comment: [Console.ReadLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Try using [`Char.GetNumericValue(String, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cdb0at4t(v=vs.110).aspx) on your `Console.ReadLine()`

Answer (score 0):

Change the loop to

```
while (x <= 30) {  
    Console.Write(x);
    if (x < 30) { // Execute for all except for x == 30
        Console.Write(", ");
    }
    x++;
}
```

`String.Join` is for joining the items of an array. It's not what you want here.

You could as well use a `StringBuilder`. It allows to remove the last `", "`.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
while (x <= 30) {  
    sb.Append(x).Append(", ");
    x++;
}
sb.Length -= 2;  // Remove the 2 last characters ", "
Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe something like this?

```
void Main()
{
  int x;
  List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

  while (true)
  {
     Console.WriteLine ("Enter a whole number between 1 and 25 or 0 to end:");
     string input = Console.ReadLine();

     bool isInteger = int.TryParse(input, out x);

     if (!isInteger || x < 0 || x > 25)
     {
        Console.WriteLine (@"Didn't I tell you ""Enter a whole number between 1 and 25 or 0 to end? Try again""");
        continue;
     }

     if (x == 0)
     {
       if (numbers.Count () == 0)
       {
        Console.WriteLine ("Pity you quit the game too early.");
       }
       else
       {
        Console.WriteLine (@"You have entered {0} numbers. The  numbers you entered were:[{1}]
Their sum is:{2} 
and their average is:{3}", 
           numbers.Count, 
           string.Join(",", numbers.Select (n => n.ToString())), 
           numbers.Sum(), 
           numbers.Average ());
       }
       break;
     }
     else
     {
       numbers.Add(x);
     }
   }
}
```